# Caching and php: Serving generated file static to speed up requests

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In code, my question is:

```
if(file_exists( c/ $requesturl ) 
serve( c/ $requesturl )
else
serve( index.php?blah )
```

---

In human form:

My script generates CSS. This is pretty intensive, so I built in caching.

People request:
http://domain.com/css/1lfi4wg.css2

Which is rewritten:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)\.css$  index.php?cssfilename=$1&generate
```

This works. After the above is visited, a cachefile is generated, which also works:

http:// domain.com/css **/c/** 1lfi4wg.css2

Now I want to serve the generated file (/c/*) as the original request. I now do this in the php file itself, but I guess doing this with htaccess is quicker.

I now have this which does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1.css [L]
```

Comment: What is your policy for caching the CSS file? Understanding this is critical to understanding how the caching should be implemented. You need to go back a couple of steps and look at where the file is generated - mod_rewrite probably has nothing to do with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*REQUEST_FILENAME* already is an absolute file system path. Try the URI path in *REQUEST_URI* or the matched string of the `RewriteRule` pattern instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^.*\.css$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# OR
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.*\.css$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$0 [L]
```